# Как заменить элемент символьного массива на более длинный символ?

Tags: c, массивы, символы

Есть символьный массив А
И его элемент А[7]=i;
Как можно вместо этой i записать в массив , например, это ahjvf ? A[7]='ahjvf'
Или это невозможно, из-за того, что все элементы кодируются одним байтом ?

Comment: Невозможно. Каждый элемент массива char* - это char (1 байт)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массив символов - это всего лишь блок последовательно размещенных `char` (в `c` именно `char` ассоциируется с байтом).

Что касается `c`, то в си в одиночные кавычки заключается **один символ**, в то время как в двойные кавычки - **0 и более**. Выражения в одиночных кавычках имеют тип `int` (однако если это один символ, его значение не должно быть больше байта, т.е. конструкция `char a = 'a';` является вполне правильной и приемлимой), а выражения в двойных кавычках - `const char[]` (по сути - указатель на первый элемент последовательности символов):

```
// В данном случае тип выражения 's' - char
char a = 's';

// А вот этот код не скомпилируется, т.к. символ где?
char a = '';

// Этот код скомпилируется, но компилятор выдаст вам предупреждение:
char a = 'abc';

// Кстати, вот этот код является вполне рабочим, т.к. между кавычками заключен пробел
char a = ' '; 

// Вот это уже строка
char *a = "some text";

// Это тоже строка, но из 1 символа:
char *a = "s";

// И даже это - строка:
char *a = "";
```

Вам может показаться, что последний пример совершенно бессмысленный. Куда указывает `char *`, если строка пустая? Все довольно просто - в `c` строки, которые вы задаете в кавычках, занимают места ровно на 1 байт больше, чем имеют символов, т.к. все строки в `c` заканчиваются символом `\0` - в общем, нулем. И даже если вы скажете компилятору:

```
char *a = "abc";
```

То в память он запишет байты

```
97 98 99 0
```

Что касается `char a = 'abc';`: это валидная конструкция, однако то, что вам запишут в переменную `a`, зависит от компилятора, и поэтому данную конструкцию использовать не следует (о чем и увидите вы в предупреждении при компиляции такого кода).

Учитывая все вышесказанное, понятно, почему компилятор вам любезно сообщит, что `'ahjvf'` для него не имеет смысла (так как это уже 5 символов (байт), а не один). Поэтому если вы хотите изменить часть строки (`char *`), то можете попробовать что-то вроде:

```
A[7] = 'a';
A[7 + 1] = 'h';
...
A[7 + 4] = 'f';
```

Или же:

```
char *strToCopy = "ahjvf";
strncpy(&A[7], strToCopy, strlen(strToCopy));
```

Заметьте, что в последнем примере количество копируемых символов - `strlen(strToCopy)`, и в это количество не включен завершающий `'\0'`. Это сделано для того, чтобы `strncpy` не завершила нам этим нулем строку раньше времени.

Comment: 1) "_выражения в одиночных кавычках имеют тип `char`_" — неверно, в языке C одиночный символ или последовательность из нескольких символов, заключённых в одинарные кавычки имеет тип `int`. 2) "_выражения в двойных кавычках — `char *`_" — неверно, последовательность символов в двойных кавычках имеет тип "массив элементов типа `char`". 3) "`'abc';`" — это корректный код, см. п. 1. [Пример](https://ideone.com/WvwidW).

Comment: @wololo все верно, просто не хотел слишком вдаваться в подробности. Поправлю ответ насчет п.1 и п.2, про п.3 напишу строчку о том, что реализация данной фичи - `implementation dependent` и это не следует использовать